# How i can remove only one letter from a text if it has multiple

Tags: python

How i can remove letter from the position

```
string1 = 'BPBPBPPPBPPPPPPBBBBPPBPBPPBPPPPBBPBPPBPBPP'
letter_4 = string1[3]
new_text = re.sub(letter_4,'', string1)
```

The resault is BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

The result I want is to remove only the letter number 4, which is 'P'

Comment: You could remove it like this `string[:3] + string[4:]`.

Comment: Thanks you su much Carlos Horn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python strings are immutable, so you cannot update them in place.
There are several ways to remove it. Which way is best depends on your other code and how you will "plug" it in your algorithm. Maybe you could describe problem which you are solving.

1. converting to list and back, slow on long strings, but readable, and you can do other edit operations on it

```py
chars = list(string1)
chars[3:4] = []
new_text = ''.join(chars)
```

2. joining two substring without unwanted position as @Carlos commented,

```py
new_text = string1[:3] + string1[4:]
```

3. replacing only first instance, not exactly what you asked, but good to know

```py
new_text = string1.replace('B', '', count=1)
```

Hope you can build you algorithm with some of these.

Answer (score 1):

As Carlos Horn said in his comment, to remove a character at index `n` in a string, you can simply use

```
st = "Hello there"
n = 6
st = st[:n]+st[n:]
```

In this case specifically:

```
string1 = 'BPBPBPPPBPPPPPPBBBBPPBPBPPBPPPPBBPBPPBPBPP'
n = 3
new_text = string1[:n]+string[n+1:]
```